# How to efficiently get the has_many values from a subset of records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I have the following classes:

```
class PinTiming < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :pin
  has_many :propagation_segments
  has_many :flags
end

class Pin < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :block
  has_many :pin_timings
end

class Block < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :comp_report
  has_many :pins
  has_many :pin_timings, through: :pins 
end
```

I would like to be able to get all of the pin_timings from a subset of the blocks.  I think I need a join, but I have been having a hard time figuring out the correct syntax.

For example I can find the blocks I want to limit my search for using this:

```
blocks_of_interest = Block.where("name LIKE ? OR name LIKE ?", "%i\_drv\_16t%", "%i\_cells\_byte%cells%cell%")
```

When I am trying to find the pin_timings I want I search like so:

```
rise_pin_timings = PinTiming.where("phase LIKE '%R@L%' and source LIKE ?", "%RWL_C_BYTE_#{a}\(%\)")
```

I want to either restrict the PinTiming query to only consider PinTimings that can be found in the blocks_of_interest or I want the Block query to return all the underlying pin_timings,  so I can further filter them later.  I think I would like to figure out how to do both case and then choose the faster solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I beleive you are looking for something like:

```
class PinTiming < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :pin
  has_one :block, through: :pin
  has_many :propagation_segments
  has_many :flags
end
```

---

```
PinTiming.joins(:block)
  .where("pin_timings.phase LIKE '%R@L%' AND pin_timings.source LIKE ?", "%RWL_C_BYTE_#{a}\(%\)")
  .where("blocks.name LIKE ? OR blocks.name LIKE ?", "%i\_drv\_16t%", "%i\_cells\_byte%cells%cell%")
```

Note that you need to specify the table in the WHERE clause when joining.

If you really want to split it up:

```
blocks = Block.where("blocks.name LIKE ? OR blocks.name LIKE ?", "%i\_drv\_16t%", "%i\_cells\_byte%cells%cell%")
rise_pin_timings = PinTiming.joins(:blocks)
                            .where("pin_timings.phase LIKE '%R@L%' AND pin_timings.source LIKE ?", "%RWL_C_BYTE_#{a}\(%\)")
                            .where(block: { id: blocks})
```

Comment: I think a key thing I missed was the has_one :block, through: :pin method.  I think my original design had a block_id column in the pin_timings table, which in the end I was never able to populate (I for get why)

Comment: You want to avoid duplicating foreign keys on multiple levels as Rails will only ever set one foreign key when assigning associations.  `PinTiming belongs_to :block` would duplicate `pins.block_id` as `pin_timings.block_id`. So setting up an indirect association here with `has_one :block, through: :pin` is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

First you can get the block_of_interest ids:

```
block_ids = Block.where("name LIKE ? OR name LIKE ?", 
            "%i\_drv\_16t%", "%i\_cells\_byte%cells%cell%").pluck(:id)
```

Then you can get all PinTimming from these block ids:

```
PinTiming.joins(pin: :block).where(blocks: { id: block_ids} )
```

**EDIT**

As max suggested, you can do it in one step without getting block ids first:

```
PinTiming.joins(pin: :block).where(blocks: { 
  id: Block.where("name LIKE ? OR name LIKE ?", 
                  "%i\_drv\_16t%", "%i\_cells\_byte%cells%cell%")} )
```

Comment: `.pluck(:id)` is not needed. If you just pass a relation ActiveRecord can use it as a subselect instead which is more efficient.

Comment: I still have to give this one a try as well,  for your edited suggestion, I would still need a where clase for the the pin_timings conditions,  right?